# how to set checked item true or false in multi checkbox react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a small request

**I want to know how to set checked item true or false in multi checkbox by Sub Terms react native**

In the following code, when I click on the checkbox, I want to change the relevant item in the array in function onchecked() and update the component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  CheckBox,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

const terms = [
  {
    term_id: 21,
    name: "Clothing",
    checked: false,
    children: [
      {
        term_id: 24,
        name: "Accessories",
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            term_id: 25,
            name: "Scarf",
            checked: false,
            children: [],
          },
          {
            term_id: 22,
            name: "Tshirts",
            checked: false,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default function Categoris() {
  const [unSelectedterms, setSelectionTerms] = useState(terms);

  const onchecked = (id) => {
    console.log(id);

    setSelectionTerms(unSelectedterms);
  };

  const recursive = (data, level = 0) => {
    return data.map((item, key) =>
      item.children?.length ? (
        <>
          {renderItem(level, item.name, item.term_id, item.checked, key)}
          {recursive(item.children, level + 1)}
        </>
      ) : (
        renderItem(level, item.name, item.term_id, item.checked, key)
      )
    );
  };

  const renderItem = (level, name, id, checked, key) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}
      key={key}
      onPress={() => {
        onchecked(id);
      }}
    >
      <CheckBox
        value={checked}
        onValueChange={() => {
          onchecked(id);
        }}
      />

      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        {name}
        {id} {level > 0 && "- ".repeat(level)}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  return <View style={styles.container}>{recursive(unSelectedterms)}</View>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 50,
  },
});
```

In the following code, when I click on the checkbox, I want to change the relevant item in the array in function onchecked() and update the component.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write some code to traverse the `terms` tree and update the correct `checked` value, but I might suggest another approach. Instead store the `checked` state separately from the `terms` tree to simplify state updates.

```
const [checkedStates, setCheckedStates] = useState({});
const onChecked(id) => {
  // this will toggle based on the current value of the checkbox
  setCheckedStates(current => ({
    ...current,
    [id]: !current[id],
  });
}
...

// and then in the recursive call
{renderItem(level, item.name, item.term_id, !!checkedStates[item.id], key)}
```

This approach should avoid a more complicated tree traversal and update at the cost of an extra piece of state. If there isn't a need to update other properties in `terms` that's the tradeoff I would choose, but if other pieces of `terms` can be updated then maybe the tree traversal is a better option.